# Getting openssl stream in node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, node.js, stream

I have a server that's using TLS 1.0
It gives me an infinite stream of data on the terminal when the command

```
~$ openssl s_client -connect 'serveraddress':5000
```

This provides me with a realtime xml data stream of what my server is currently doing.
I want to connect to it using node.js or any other way that provides me with the possibility to push this data stream as a websocket or directly onto a JS, but I can't seem to figure out how. Can any of you please help?
Thanks :)

Comment: Ok so, if I get what you want, you want to redirect the output stream of your server to a program that sends this data over the web? I don't ask this question often, but why would you want to do that?

Comment: Did you think about making an RSS stream with your XML data?

Comment: @Sh3ljohn: I actually want to use this output stream on a javascript to plot a graph. But since this xml stream is based on an https instead of a wss I am not able to use this directly in my JS. I am just looking for a way to access the data. Redirecting through a local server that outputs it as a websocket is one way of solving my problem.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use Unix pipes then? Here is a good tuto: http://www.ucblueash.edu/thomas/Intro_Unix_Text/IO_Redir_Pipes.html

Comment: I don't know how to use them. I'll go through it and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like that should solve your problem.

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('bash');

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Sending stdin to terminal');
    terminal.stdin.write("openssl s_client -connect 'serveraddress':5000");
    terminal.stdin.end();
}, 1000);
```

**Edit:**
Try this for a working example:

```
terminal.stdin.write("ping www.google.de");
```

Comment: I tried this. It gives me this error: "child process exited with code 255"
Any way to fix this?

Comment: Well, I think something with your openssl command is wrong then. When I try terminal.stdin.write("ping www.google.de"); it works perfect.